# Multiple month columns without inline subqueries

Tags: mysql

Is there a more effective way to return multiple columns from a table that contains a date column instead of using inline subqueries?

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `data` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 1 AS `Jan`),
       (SELECT ...) // Feb, Mar, etc.
```

Because having 12 inline subqueries is taxing on the query engine, right?

Comment: Can you give the table structure ?

Comment: @david I don't think table structure is necessary, just know that my table contains a date column, and from that I want to create "artifical" month columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) as `YEAR`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`)=1 THEN `value` ELSE 0 END) AS `JAN`, 
... 
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`)
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `data` GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
```